# Simple Javascript Checkins

Tags: post, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

Can anyone show me a quick example of posting a checkin with javascript using FB.api('/me/checkins', 'post', etc?? Mine doesn't seem to work. Also does anyone know if this will take a date variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The me/checkins appears to be a read-only table (there's no permission to request to do a add). Per the documentation, you can add/remove comments on an existing check-in as well as add/remove a user's like of that check-in.

From the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> `user_checkins` : Provides read access to the authorized user's 
>   check-ins or a friend's check-ins that the user can see.

**Edit**
My mistake, I missed seeing the `publish_checkins` permission in the list there...disregard.
Did you happen to try posting a checkin via the Graph API Explorer tool?  Did it work?

Comment: Holy crapolla!  I totally missed seeing that permission in the list.  Did you try posting to the checking via the Graph API Explorer tool?

Comment: I got it working. However nothing I do will do exactly what I want. I tried feed, checkins, events, but there is no way possible to backdate a post like I was hoping for. It's not allowed yet... maybe one day.

Comment: Glad to help.  Return the favor and see if you can help answer a question here on stackoverflow.